# How to access an input element by a non-standard attribute?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have several input fields where the name and id attributes change based on which server this is rolled out on, and *class* is also not unique. The only unique attribute for each input field is in "roiname".
How can I use jQuery to get the value of this field in a way that works across servers?

```
<input roiname="smallLocations" name="__field_13102" id="e5634b55-d6cc-4b32-a5aa-2120b4845dbb" type="number" class="form-control FormTextbox__Input" placeholder="4" value="" min="0" step="1" data-f-datainput="">
```

I tried something like this:

```
var smallLocations = $(":input").attr("smallLocations").val();
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: `$('*[roiname]')[0].val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for the value of the *attribute*, you're looking for the value of the *input*.  (Also, your `input` doesn't *have* an attribute called "smallLocations", that's the value of one of the attributes.)

Something like this:

```
$('input[roiname="smallLocations"]').val()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current logic doesn't work as you're using `attr()` which *retrieves the value* of an attribute, it does not find an element by that attribute.

To fix this you need to use an attribute selector:

```js
var roiname = $(':input[roiname]').val();
console.log(roiname);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input roiname="smallLocations" value="123" name="__field_13102" id="e5634b55-d6cc-4b32-a5aa-2120b4845dbb" type="number" class="form-control FormTextbox__Input" placeholder="4" value="" min="0" step="1" data-f-datainput="">
```

Comment: I think the colon before the tag name is a typo.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the hint :) Though I guess it's not the comments section the place for this.

Answer (score 0):

use the sizzle has attr selector

`var smallLocations = $("input[roiname]").val();`

Documentation here

https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/